# Changing from .forEach to for Loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change this piece of javascript to for loop.

How would I do that?

```
 function initCovers(coverOpts) {
    coverOpts.forEach(function (opts) {
      init(opts);
    });
  }
```

---

code: https://jsfiddle.net/vhzdr1fk/

```
function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    if (cover.coverOpts.show) {
      show(document.querySelector(cover.coverOpts.show));
    }
    if (cover.coverOpts.hide) {
      hide(document.querySelector(cover.coverOpts.hide));
    }
  }
  function initCovers(coverOpts) {
    coverOpts.forEach(function (opts) {
      init(opts);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create a normal for loop

```
function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    if (cover.coverOpts.show) {
      show(document.querySelector(cover.coverOpts.show));
    } 
    if (cover.coverOpts.hide) {
      hide(document.querySelector(cover.coverOpts.hide));
    }
  }
  function initCovers(coverOpts) {
    for(var i = 0; i < coverOpts.length; i++) {
      init(coverOpts[i]);
    }
  }
```